# Spinner probability

Tags: probability

Based on the spinner below answer the following:
(a) In two consecutive spins what, is the probability of a C followed by a B? 
Answer:

(b) In a single spin, what is the probability of obtaining a B given the spinner did not land on a C? 
Answer: 
!https://webwork.math.nau.edu/webwork2_files/tmp/MLanzetta_114_A//gif/rau7-3161-setWebwork_4prob2image1.png

I have tried several ways and just don't get it. I need someone to help break it down like a 3rd grader! HELP!

Comment: What is the spinner?

Comment: Sorry, my picture did not show up.

Comment: checkmark please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a) C is $1/3$ and B is $1/2$ so probability of C followed by B is $1/6$.

b) Since it didn't land on C, and we know that B is $1/2$ and A is $1/6$, with C effectively "eliminated" from the possible outcomes, we can now say that since the prob of B is $3$ times as likely as the prob of A, we can say the prob of getting a B is now $75$%.

It helps in b) if you convert everything to $6$ths so prob A = $1/6$, prob B = $3/6$, and prob C = $2/6$.  Since we are told it didn't land on C, it would be like spinning a different spinner with only $2$ values on it where B was $3$ times as likely as A.  That would mean that B would have to be $75$% chance and A would have to be $25$% chance.

Another way of looking at b) is that originally, option C gave us a $2/6$th doubt that we spun an A or a B.  Since we were told that the C didn't occur, that $2/6$th doubt is now gone which means that the other $4/6$ths probability of landing on A or B has to be scaled up to be $6/6$th so we need to multiply the original probabilities of both A and B by $3/2$s to do so.  This may confuse you a little so if it does don't worry about it since this is just an alternate explanation that gives the same answer.

Comment: YES! OK. That makes way more since. Thank you for your help! I need you to tutor me for this whole class! Note to self, MAT 114 Should not be done online!

Comment: I am new to this site, is there any way to pm?